# Integration of combination of Bessel Function and Exponential Function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have read "Watson:Treatise Theory of Bessel Function", "Table of Integration, Series and Product", "Handbook of Mathematical Functions, Formulas, Graphs and Mathematical Tables" and other online literature. But I unable to solve a integration of combination of Bessel and Exponential function. The function is 
$$
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\iota \omega t} I_{0}\left [
b\sqrt{1-t^{2}} \right ]dt\
$$

I am using Walform Mathematica 9.1 for Mathematical analysis. Please Suggest me particular solution, Method or formulas to integrate this combined function. Also suggest any  other Software for this type of integration.

Comment: As it stands, I don't see any particular reason to expect this to have a generic closed-form solution. Can you describe the motivation behind this integral?

Comment: I have to develop Fractional Fourier Transform of this Bessel Function. I read somewhere its explanation of integration in Book Review: George A. Campbell and Ronald M. Foster, Fourier Integrals for Practical Applications  by  J. K. Lamond. In history it was solve by Ben Lagon. But I have no access to these literature. Please help.

Comment: When you say 'solved', in what sense do you mean? I could well believe that there's a series expansion (in powers of $b$, say). It's harder for me to be confident that there's a closed-form solution, though it's not impossible.

Comment: Two observations: The imaginary part vanishes. By changing the integration limits to $\pm1$, and letting $\omega=b=1$, the value becomes $2$.

Comment: The function was part of kaiser window function proposed Sir J.F.Kaier. He told to interviewer(in an interview at IEEE website) that he picked this function and Fourier transform pair from Ben Lagon office board where he was solved recently. The result of this integration on page no. 698 (point-5) in the book  "Table of Integration, Series and Product" But I can't match them. try by series expansion, subsitution for whole square root term.

Comment: Do you mean 6.616.5 of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik? Note that that integration formula has the term $e^{- a t}$ with $a>0$, and has limits $[-1,1]$. The former can perhaps be resolved by analytic continuation, but the latter is much thornier since getting to different limits is typically as hard as doing the indefinite integral.

Comment: Yes sir it is 6.616.5

Comment: Please share this question.I have to solve it at any condition. It is so tough to solve and I have not much literature except stated above about Bessel integrals

Comment: @lucian I think user need all steps. that are involve to solve this integration.because user don't have strong mathematical background.

Comment: I am basically from engineering background.

Comment: Please suggest me any relevant solved example @Semiclassical

Comment: @Harry Peter please give me some clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is derived by Slepian and Pollak in 1961 and this is also know by Prolate-spheroidal wave function. For more detail read these articles

[Prolate spheroidal wave functions, Fourier analysis, and uncertainty-I](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol40-1961/articles/bstj40-1-43.pdf)

[Prolate spheroidal wave functions, Fourier analysis, and uncertainty-II](http://www.ascend.com/bstj/vol40-1961/articles/bstj40-1-65.pdf)

In 1964 J.F. kaiser introduce this function with simple approximate to family of  window function nearly ideal properties

Everybody thanks for suggestions